# How do I understand this R function?

Tags: r, function

```
mfibR <- local({
    memo <- c(1, 1, rep(NA, 1000))
    f <- function(x) {
        if (x == 0) 
            return(0)
        if (x < 0) 
            return(NA)
        if (x > length(memo)) 
            stop("x too big for implementation")
        if (!is.na(memo[x])) 
            return(memo[x])
        ans <- f(x - 2) + f(x - 1)
        memo[x] <<- ans
        ans
    }
})
```

It has no function body, but it actually returns the Fibonacci sequence correctly.

Comment: *It has no function body* is like saying `myapply <- apply` has no function body (it was created in an unconventional way). You should look at `print(mfibR)` or `body(mfibR)` to see it does have a function body. It may also help you understand how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from `?local` help page.

> **local** evaluates an expression in a local environment. It is equivalent
>   to evalq except that its default argument creates a new, empty
>   environment. This is useful to create anonymous recursive functions
>   and as a kind of limited namespace feature since variables defined in
>   the environment are not visible from the outside.

Do go through the examples from the help page of the `local` function. It shows how local is used to create anonymous functions. `local` will return last evaluated expression.

Comment: +1 - but there is a bit more to be said about how it works. It returns a recursive function (`f`) with an environment variable (`memo`) so that things that have already been computed once can be stored and won't be computed again.

Comment: @flodel - agreed that answer could have been more explicitly related to example posted. However, I actually very much wanted user to read the `?local` instead of giving out whole explanation here.

Comment: +1.  Looking up "closure" and "recursion" as general programming terms may also be helpful for understanding here.